# Display slick slider in Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I want to show a slick slider inside of a Bootstrap dropdown element.
The problem is, that the slider doesn't work if the dropdown isn't open from the beginning.
Also the prev/next buttons doesn't work.

Here's my current code as a working example: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/YzwdgQK

I'm using default styles from Bootstrap and slick.

The JS code from the slider:

```
$('.mini-cart-items').slick({
    dots: false,
    nextArrow: $('#minicartnext'),
    prevArrow: $('#minicartprev'),
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    mobileFirst: true,
    vertical:true,
});
```

If the dropdown is open from the beginning, everything works fine.
Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dropdowns are only designed to hold Bootstrap dropdown items. You can put other bits of content in a popover.

First, add this script after jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            html: true,
            sanitize: false,
        })
    })
</script>
```

Second, add `data-toggle="popover"` to the trigger.

Third, use the `title` and `data-content` attributes to set the title and content.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/techboyg5/pen/mdVagJW)

Comment: thank you! But I need to use the dropdown component for this.

Comment: Sorry, but I noticed an issue with the code snippet posted above. It said sanatize instead of sanitize. Now it should work.